# Ubuntu 20.04 XDG_SEAT, XDG_VTNR, XDG_SESSION_ID env variables are not set

Tags: gnome-shell, lightdm, 20.04, gdm

I set up and installed Ubuntu 20.04 using `debootstrap` method

```
  debootstrap --arch=amd64 --variant=buildd focal ./focal_amd64  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
```

then installed all the rest.
It runs well except old and new  GNOME bugs. I have been using it for ten days.
The day before I noticed that it's missing `XDG_SESSION_ID`.
When I dug in I noticed that it's also missing  `XDG_SEAT`, `XDG_VTNR`, `XDG_SESSION_ID` variables.
 I read that those variables are set by `pam modules` https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/pam_systemd.html

I added `session optional pam_loginuid.so` and `session optional pam_systemd.so` to `/etc/pam.d/lightdm`.

I tried both of the display managers `gdm3` and `lightdm`. They both fail to set environment variables: `XDG_SEAT`, `XDG_VTNR`, `XDG_SESSION_ID`.

`XDG_SEAT_PATH` is only set in `lightdm`

I am having a difficulty at debugging it. How can I know  which process set those variables which is missing in my system?

Comment: I'm on lubuntu 20.04 and `$ echo $XDG_SESSION_ID` displays
`5
`